# Spark - Statistical calculations sorted by timestamps ranges

Tags: python, apache-spark, group-by, pyspark, aggregate

I'm trying to calculate statistical measures based on a range of hours and\or days.

Meaning, I have a CSV file that is something like this:

```
TRANSACTION_URL    START_TIME        END_TIME           SIZE    FLAG
www.google.com     20170113093210    20170113093210     150      1
www.cnet.com       20170113114510    20170113093210     150      2
```

START_TIME and END_TIME are in `yyyyMMddhhmmss` format.

I'm first converting it to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format by using the following code:

```
from_pattern = 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'
to_pattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'

log_df = log_df.withColumn('START_TIME', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(
    log_df['START_TIME'].cast(StringType()), from_pattern), to_pattern).cast(TimestampType()))
```

And afterward, I would like to use `groupBy()` in order to calculate, for example, the mean of the SIZE column, based on the transaction TIME frame.

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
for all transactions that are between 09:00 to 11:00
    calculate SIZE mean

for all transactions that are between 14:00 to 16:00
    calculate SIZE mean
```

And also:

```
for all transactions that are in a WEEKEND date
    calculate SIZE mean

for all transactions that are NOT in a WEEKEND date
    calculate SIZE mean
```

I DO know how to use groupBy for a 'default' configuration, such as calculating statistical measures for SIZE column, based on FLAG column values. I'm using something like:

```
log_df.cache().groupBy('FLAG').agg(mean('SIZE').alias("Mean"), stddev('SIZE').alias("Stddev")).\
    withColumn("Variance", pow(col("Stddev"), 2)).show(3, False)
```

So, my questions are:

1. How to achieve such grouping and calculating, for a range of hours? (1st pseudo code example)
2. How to achieve such grouping and calculating, by dates? (2nd pseudo code example)

Is there any python package that can receive `yy-MM-dd` and return `true` if it's a weekend date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a function encode_dates which receives the date and returns a sequence of encoding for all times periods you are interested in. So for example for tuesday 9-12 it would return Seq("9-11","10-12","11-13","weekday"). This would be a regular scala function (unrelated to spark).

now you can make it a UDF and add it as a column and explode the column so you will have multiple copies. Now all you need to do is add this column for the groupby.

So it would look something like this:

```
val encodeUDF = udf(encode_dates _)
log_df.cache().withColumn("timePeriod", explode(encodeUDF($"start_date", $"end_date").groupBy('FLAG', 'timePeriod').agg(mean('SIZE').alias("Mean"), stddev('SIZE').alias("Stddev")).
withColumn("Variance", pow(col("Stddev"), 2)).show(3, False)
```

Comment: Writing a function like you suggested, seems like overkill for my scenario - all transactions in my CSV are usually 1sec - 10 sec long, at most.
Maybe I can write a function that receives `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`, and returns something like `Morning, Weekend`, but i don't know how to: **1. Apply it to every transaction "on the fly" -**
**2. After applying it on every transaction, calculate Mean/STDDEV on all records that are for example `Afternoon, Weekend`** (FLAG is irrelevant for those calculations)

Comment: And even better - apply my function to every transaction, and for each transaction that isn't in `Morning` or in `Afternoon` time - remove if from the dataframe, e.g transaction that is in 13:00-13:01 will be removed (which will make the afterward calculations work on a reduced datafrmae) - But i have no idea how to acheive such behavior once i'll write such function

Comment: This is your business logic. You need to define a function which says: "given a time period, which time periods I want to include in the statistics". Once you have this you basically multiply your data to appear in all the time periods and group by it. You can probably do something more efficient by writing a custom UDAF but i am not sure it will end up being as efficient.

Comment: Just to make sure it is clear what the logic here does: 1. you make a function f(time)->time periods list. 2. The code in the answer basically will apply it to every transaction and calculate the statistics. It doesn't really matter if you "apply it on the fly" or not. In practice you will be doing 2 passes: one for calculating the data and the second for aggregate.

Comment: Ok, but as i mentioned creating a list of time periods will generate huge list, due to the fact that all transactions are at most 10sec long, and i need time ranges of couple of hours. If i'll go in your suggested direction, but make a function `f(START_TIME, END_TIME)` which outputs a list of 2 objects e.g. `Morning, Weekday`, `Noon, Weekend`,`Evening, Weekday`, etc. and use the suggested `explode` method, will it still do the trick?

Comment: Yes. Basically what you are doing is adding a column to groupby and multiplying each element to have an instance in each time period. If the result is a list of 2 objects it will mean multiplying the data by two before the groupby. You can still have "11-13","Weekend" as a response if you want to get more refined results, it doesn't matter. The groupby will just give results for "11-13" and for "weekend" as two lines in the resulting dataframe.

Comment: I've built a function and created UDF. when trying to use `explode(encodeUDF($"START_TIME", $"END_TIME"))` i'm getting `syntax error`. When trying `explode(encodeUDF(col["START_TIME"], col[$"END_TIME"]))` , i'm getting `"cannot resolve 'explode(bidani(START_TIME, END_TIME))' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType`

Comment: It seems your function expects to recieve an array. Instead it recieves a string. In general your function should recieve two strings (or convert the input column to dateTime and recieve 2 scala datetime) and return an array of strings.

Comment: My functions is defined as follows: `def bidani(start_time, end_time): 
    start_time = str(start_time)
    end_time = str(end_time)`

According to the error it seems the problem is with `explode` syntax who expects an array\map

Comment: It does, as far as i understand. see here - http://pastebin.com/XHRL3qvp

Comment: This seems fine. How did you define the udf? did you set the return type as an array of strings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134064/discussion-between-adiel-and-assaf-mendelson).